# How to achieve the controlled rotation in the HHL algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, hhl-algorithm

I'm trying to implement the HHL algorithm generally for any 2 x 2 hermitian matrix, but I'm having trouble with the implementation of the controlled rotation of the ancilla qubit. I've read very many posts on this site and have found two primary methods to achieve such a rotation. Also I'm a beginner with quantum computing and computer science in general so I apologize if I make any mistakes.

The goal of the rotation of the ancilla qubit is to achieve the state:
$\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n_{b}}-1}b_{j}|u_{j}\rangle|\tilde{\lambda}_{j}\rangle|0\rangle\mapsto \sum_{j=0}^{2^{n_{b}}-1}b_{j}|u_{j}\rangle|\tilde{\lambda}_{j}\rangle\Big(\sqrt{1-\frac{C^{2}}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}^{2}}}|0\rangle+\frac{C}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}}|1\rangle\Big )$

To perform this rotation we can use an Ry gate with $\theta_{j}=2\sin^{-1}\Big (  \frac{C}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}}\Big )$. The difficulty comes from the fact that the eigenvalue $\tilde{\lambda}_{j}$ is stored in a register $|\tilde{\lambda}_{j}\rangle$ and transforming the register into $|\theta_{j}\rangle=\Big|2\sin^{-1}\Big (  \frac{C}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}}\Big )\Big\rangle$ is very difficult. Once in this state, it is very easy to perform the rotation by simply breaking $|\theta_{j}\rangle$ into its bitwise pieces and controlling Ry rotations off of them.

Implementing the transformation $|\tilde{\lambda}_{j}\rangle\mapsto |2\sin^{-1}(  C/\tilde{\lambda}_{j})\rangle$ is quite difficult.
However, we can make our job somewhat easier by using the small angle approximation: $\sin^{-1}\Big (  \frac{C}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}}\Big ) \approx  \frac{C}{\tilde{\lambda}_{j}}$. That is what Cao et. al do in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2232v2.pdf) paper. I have been working on implementing this paper into Qiskit for several days with no success, I believe there to be a few issues in it that I am not sure how to deal with. I have begun looking into alternative methods for implementing the eigenvalue inversion, but it seems my only other option is to do quantum arithmetic which I would like to avoid especially if there are better options to achieve the eigenvalue inversion.

The other option I have seen posted here is classically approximating values for eigenvalues to decide the values of $\theta_{j}$ for the controlled rotation. This could be done through a variety of different methods such as Gershgorin's circle theorem to find the bounds for the eigenvalues and then choosing a value of $\theta_{j}$ from there. This is also not very easy to do, as we still have to break down the Ry gate into a series of gates controlled off of the clock register, and I am not yet sure how to do so using this method.

I am wondering if anyone has any insight into what the best method for implementing the HHL algorithm is? Or if a good method even currently exists. I've spent a long time looking for a solid method for general matrices and I haven't found one yet. Also let me know if anything else needs further explained or if there are any errors that need corrected. Thank you in advance!